# Why are some colorschemes in VIM not working?

Tags: vim

I am trying to download some VIM colorschemes but they seem not to work.
Here is an example:

http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/colors/vylight.vim

and yet another example:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=16130

I was able to install a few other colorschemes and they work. I copied them in the following directory: /usr/share/vim/vim73/colors 
As other colorschemes copied there work, I guess the location is OK. I simply use :colorscheme scheme-name(without .vim extension) and the above ones do not work. I am using VIM 7.3.

Also, any suggestions for cool VIM colorschemes for HTML, JS and PHP would be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These colorschemes are GUI-only; i.e. they only work in GVIM, not in the terminal. You'll recognize that because the contained `:highlight` commands only contain `gui[fg|bg]=...` definitions.

Plugins like [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) can take the GUI color definitions and convert them to a closely matching 256-color `cterm` color palette for high-color terminals. This helps with colorschemes that otherwise only pick from the bland default 16-color terminal color palette, or only provide GUI color definitions.

Another approach is taken by [csexact](https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/vim-csexact), which modifies the (supported) terminal's palette to exactly match Vim's GUI colors.

#### Install location

You've used the system install location to place your colorschemes. It's better to put them into your user's configuration instead: `~/.vim/colors/` (as you presumably also set them into your `~/.vimrc`).

Comment: What I was typing just now myself, except more detailed and informative (and therefore useful). :)

Comment: @ebenezer: Thanks! It's good to have so many watchful (and helpful) eyes around here.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thanks for the info... very informative indeed.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Just tried GVIM. Why would anyone use VIM over GVIM? Thanks

Comment: Vim works over SSH; some people also use multiplexers like `screen` or `tmux` to have a terminal with build scripts nearby; that's more difficult to achieve with GVIM. Apart from that, I also use GVIM 99% of the time.